# A weird error in switch statement in c++

Tags: c++

Does initialization statement can't be used in the case of switch statement ?
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
int nosenseFun(int choice){
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
            int temp = 1;
            return temp;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 2;
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it using g++, I got error message like that

```
testSwitch.cpp:14:14: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
testSwitch.cpp:12:17: error:   crosses initialization of ‘int temp’
```

Does initialization statement can't be used in the case of switch statement ?

Comment: First related link on the right.

Comment: Enclose the entire case 1: statement within braces. Then it should be fine.